# Integration with InfinityQs

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Have you ever worked with InfinityQs? I need to integrate it with my asp.net core application to get data from it. I can not find the necessary information or guide. I'm new and have no idea where to start. I would be grateful if you share your experience or a useful article.

I tried to find at least some information about working with InfinityQs in the context of a c # application, but I could not find anything